# Creating labels with Umlauts, accents, etc. in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, encoding, font

I have a problem labeling features with special characters like French accents, umlauts, etc.

I have the names in the attribute table, but names like `Niafunké` are displayed `Niafunk�`. I assume it has something to do with character coding, but where can I change that in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

I just found it myself - it's under layer properties -> General -> Data source encoding.